# Cannot install vim into msys

Tags: vim, msys

I installed msys on `C:\msys` drive. I downloaded the vim extensions `vim-7.3-2-msys-1.0.16-bin.tar.lzma` from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/mingw/files/MSYS/Extension/vim/vim-7.3-2/) and copied it to `C:\msys`. But after invoking `sh` and typing `vim` or `vi` from inside my `msys` shell `sh`, a message box pops up and says. I have posted a screenshot [here](http://postimg.org/image/ybyjb06xd/). Help me fix this issue. I don need to install `vim` separately. I need to get it working inside `msys`.

```
The program cant start because msys-iconv-2.dll is missing from your computer.
Try re installing the program to fix it.
```

Comment: Well, the problem is rather obvious: you are missing a lib. Install that lib to fix the problem.

Comment: ofcourse I know that, but the question is where do I get that lib

Comment: Have you tried searching for it?!

Comment: yes i really did try to find the lib, If any 1 of u know which 1 it is please post the link.